# How do i combine a user input function to this basic number sorter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have two pieces of code and I am trying to amalgamate the two. Basically I need a number sorter which asks the user to input values until a number equal to or less than 0 is input. Once this is done the program sorts the numbers into ascending order. So far I have code for user input that ends when a number less than 0 is entered

```
function Sample()
Loop  = true;
Count = 0;
while(Loop)
      a = input('Please input a number: ');
      if a>=0
          Count = Count+1;
      else
              Loop = false;
      end
end
fprintf('Ok, the number of inputs enetered by the user is %d',Count);
end
```

And a code to put numbers into ascending order.

```
A = [1 2 4 8 5 11 0.2];
B = zeros(size(A));           
for k = 1:numel(A)            
    [m, ind] = min(A);        
    A(ind)   = [];            
    B(k)     = m;
end
disp(B)
```

I cant however figure out how to combine the two into a single program. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can do that with the  [`input`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) function. See examples in the linked documentation

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the upper function is, is that you dont store the inputs, but only the number of inputs. Try:

```
while true:
      a = input('Please input a number: ');
      if a>=0:
          Count = Count+1;
          A(1,Count) = int(a);       % NEW
      else:
          break;
      end
end
```